# Iterate with for loop over specific columns in query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with like 70 columns and a couple million rows and need to repeat a program/function over the values limited to restrictions on different rows. Let's say it's something like

```
   index  target1  ignore1  tar2  tar3 ignore2
0      1        0      the     1     0     nor
1      2        1    value     0     1    does
2      3        0  doesn't     1     1      it
3      4        1   matter     1     1  matter
4      5        0     here     0     1    here
```

I want to do this:

```py
targets = ['target1', 'tar2', 'tar3']
for target in targets:
     df.query('@target == 1')
```

And then do other stuff to the resulting query (with, eventually a bunch of other query values).

Every search I've tried has led me to stuff like `df.query('column_name == @variable')` but nothing seems to clarify that you can (or can't) use the reference variable from the loop in place of the column name.

I've drafted 20 versions with parens and brackets and so on, and I'm not sure at this point where else to turn...

Upon convo with Ian Thompson, I include the following example:

```
data = {
  "name": ["Sally", "Mary", "John"],
  "age": [50, 40, 30],
    "race": ["H", "B", "W"],
    "Male": [0, 0, 1],
    "Rich": [0, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

categories = ("Rich", "Male")
for cat in categories:
    data_test = df.query("(@cat == 1) and (race.isin(['H', 'B']))")
    print(data_test.age.median())
```

**And now, after hunting and trying, I found this solution:**

```
categories = ("Rich", "Male")
for cat in categories:
    data_test = df.query(f"({cat} == 1) and (race.isin(['H', 'B']))")
    print(data_test.age.median())
```

And that seems to work.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do to the three columns in your `targets` variable as well as what the output should look like?

Comment: Sure - I have a binary column that determines if the row is (say) white, another for black, another for Hispanic. I have other columns that I need to limit on as well. For instance I need the Hispanic column (1) and then a slew of things to be set (age range, income range, work attendance, degree). THEN, once all that is set, I want to find the Median on a final column. Then, do it all again for the other values in the list (White, Black, etc...) automatically.

Comment: Please add that to the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And updated. I think the error is in expecting @var to work, maybe it needs to be a f{} option...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like df.query doesn't allow for '@localvariable' and that needs to be a string so df.query(f"{localvariable} ==...") should work.